# Get object values from array - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this array of objects

```
[ { id: '573267d06b2957ab24c54d59' },
  { id: '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5a' },
  { id: '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5b' },
  { id: '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5c' },
  { id: '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5d' } 
]
```

I wish to convert it to the following in NodeJs

```
[ '573267d06b2957ab24c54d59',
  '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5a',
  '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5b',
  '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5c',
  '573267d06b2957ab24c54d5d'
]
```

It seems like it should be easy given the right library/package, but I am struggling to find the right wording to "flatten" the array into the IDs of the contained objects.

Comment: If you want to use a library, go for lodash (https://lodash.com/docs#flatten). Though you might have to find a function which works for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't need to use a library, just thought that it's the kind of that that a library might be useful for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say your array of objects is called `arr`, just do this:

```
var arrayOfStrings = arr.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
});
```

`map` will iterate over the array and create a new array based on how you define your function. In this case we return the value of the `id` key in each case to build out the desired array of ids.